# How to detach a part of some value inside a array object and map into new array from AWS MongoDB values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Actually, I tried to map values (userID, userName & userBirthday) into an array object from the AWS MongoDB and I want to compare is the user's birthday is today or not. In MongoDB, the user's birthday (column name; ***dateOfBirth***) is stored in this format. "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00" So I want to get only month value & date value from this. But I'm unable to split this value from the array. How it can or is any other way to do that? I'm trouble with build this logic. So help would be much appreciated!

```
const allUsers = await helper.getAllUsers(organizationId); //get all user data
const allUserList = allUsers.Items.map(user => (
 { userId: user.id,
   userFullName: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
   userBirthday: user.dateOfBirth 
}));
const thisDay = new Date().getMonth();
const thisMonth = new Date().getDate();

const birthdayUserList = allUserList.filter(
   user => ??????? === thisDay && ??????? === thisMonth
);
```

In the last code-line, I want to get the date & month value from  ***userBirthday*** of the ***allUserList*** & compare with ***thisDay*** & ***thisMonth***. Furthermore, I attached the inside look of the ***allUserList***

```
[
 { userId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', userFullName: 'xxxxx  xxxx' }, userBirthday: 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00'},
 { userId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', userFullName: 'xxxxx  xxxx' }, userBirthday: 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00'},
 { userId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', userFullName: 'xxxxx  xxxx' }, userBirthday: 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00'},
 { userId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', userFullName: 'xxxxx  xxxx' }, userBirthday: 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00'},
 .....
]
```

Comment: If your model sets that date as a Date, the filter could just use `user.userBirthday.getDate()` and `user.userBirthday.getMonth()`, if it's not in the Date format but string instead, `allUserList` loop could return `{ userBirthday: new Date(user.dateOfBirth) }`

Comment: Thank you for your support! In here 1st one is not worked. But the second one is worked after few changes as following. `userBirthMonth: new Date(user.dateOfBirth).getMonth()` and `userBirthDate: new Date(user.dateOfBirth).getDate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const allUsers = await helper.getAllUsers(organizationId); //get all user data
const allUserList = allUsers.Items.map(user => (
 { userId: user.id,
   userFullName: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
   userBirthMonth: new Date(user.dateOfBirth).getMonth(),
   userBirthDate: new Date(user.dateOfBirth).getDate()
}));
const thisDay = new Date().getMonth();
const thisMonth = new Date().getDate();

const birthdayUserList = allUserList.filter(user =>
 user.userBirthMonth === currentMonth && user.userBirthDate === currentDate
);
```

or you can use the month & date together as follows.

```
{ userBirthday: `${new Date(user.dateOfBirth).getMonth()}-${new Date(user.dateOfBirth).getDate()} }
```

in the `allUserList`  & you should store the current date as mentioned formate of above.

```
const currentDate = `${new Date().getMonth()}-${new Date().getDate()}`
```

Logic can use as follows.

```
const birthdayUserList = allUserList.filter( user => user.userBirthday === currentDate);
```